# Is there a way to redefine the bibliography output in biblatex w/ apacite citestyle? The german translation seems to be wrong

Tags: latex, language-translation, bibliography, biblatex

I am trying to create a bibliography for my thesis using biblatex with the APA-citestyle. I also use the babel with german option since my thesis is in German.

My bibfile looks like this:

```
% literature.bib
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is the title},
  url = {https://www.google.de/},
  urldate = {2020-01-10}
}
```

..and my main.tex like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{A01}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the bibliography]

However, on online sources the "accessed" link seems to be translated in a wrong way. It outputs "...Verfügbar + date + unter +url" which translates to "...Available + date + from url". But the date is the date I accessed the url, not the publishing date. If I change the language in the babel package to American, the output is correct.

Since I am new to Latex and Biblatex specifically, I wonder if there is a way to redefine the Output of the urldate field. I am using the Overleaf editor if that is of importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a version prior to the commit https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/commit/79848cf1e29a2fb0c01b2420ad4753a34b5d2bbd or fix the translation yourself:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  retrieved = {abgerufen am},
  from      = {von},
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is the title},
  url = {https://www.google.de/},
  urldate = {2020-01-10}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{A01}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm, thank you very much :)

Comment: @jnthn You're welcome!